# Peak Current of PWM

Tags: pwm, high-current

I am designing a controller for a hotwire cutter. As measured, the resistance measured is 1 \$\Omega\$. The power is switched on and off with a 555 astable mode to produce a pwm of \$V_{on}=12\$ V and \$V_{off}=0\$ V.

Although I can adjust the duty cycle so that the average current is 4 A or less (at which the power supply is rated), I am drawing 12 A during each \$V_{on}\$ period. By adding a capacitor, the instantaneous current shall stabilize but the initial current is still enormous and worrying. Any possible remedies?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fep9dm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Well, to get hot these things need a decent amount of power and you have to provide it, I dont see where the problem is

Comment: I used a DMM to measure the current. The 10A max DMM showed a 11.2A and the 4A psu immediately shuts off with smoke from hotwire. I've also test 2A is more than sufficient and cuts acrylics but I just need to cut foam. Overpower is really a problem.

Comment: So drive it with less voltage via e.g. a buck converter (or build your own).

Comment: That is a nice suggestion, sir. But as for my original pwm design, any idea to reduce the initial currents, say an inductor or capacitor?

Comment: add an inductor and cap and you have basically a buck converter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGo2u1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could greatly increase the PWM frequency and place a power inductor in series with the wire. Say you switch at 50kHz and you want 1A of ripple, the inductor would have to be a few hundred uH, and must be rated to not saturate at something like 5A. You also need a Schottky diode. No capacitor is required -- unless you care about EMI.. but it could be a pretty good broadband RF jammer without it if the loop area of the wire is large.

Comment: Concise and comprehensive. Thanks also @PlasmaHH for his/her insight.